# Input incorrect Assembly x86 NASM

Tags: assembly, io, x86, gdb, nasm

I have been looking at this for hours and can't figure out why after my second input my string stored from the first input changes.

When I run sample run like this:

Please enter the id: 12

Please enter the name: jay

When I run this part of the code for just standard inputing and output gdb shows that id1Buf has value "12\n" after first read. Then it prompts to enter name so when I enter jay id1Buf value changes to "12\njay" for some reason. Cant figure it out, it would be great if someone could help.

```
SECTION .text                               ;.text section

global _start                               ;start section

_start:                                     ;start
    main:     
        ;;write out
        mov eax, SYSCALL_WRITE              ;write function
        mov ebx, STDOUT                     ;write value
        mov ecx, id                         ;address of message
        mov edx, lenid                      ;length of message
        int 80h                             ;interrupt

        ;;read user input
        mov eax, SYSCALL_READ               ;read function
        mov ebx, STDIN                      ;read in value
        mov ecx, id1Buf                     ;store read value in id1Buf
        mov edx, IDBUFLEN                   ;length of idbuf
        int 80h                             ;interrupt

        ;;write out
        mov eax, SYSCALL_WRITE              ;write function
        mov ebx, STDOUT                     ;write value
        mov ecx, name                       ;address of message
        mov edx, lenname                    ;length of message
        int 80h                             ;interrupt

        ;;read user input
        mov eax, SYSCALL_READ               ;read function
        mov ebx, STDIN                      ;read in value
        mov ecx, name1Buf                   ;store read value in name1Buf
        mov edx, NAMEBUFLEN                 ;length of namebuf
        int 80h                             ;interrupt

        mov [name1readlen], eax             ;store length of name
```

This is some of the other code for reference.

```
;;constants 
%define STDIN 0                             ;read function
%define STDOUT 1                            ;write function
%define STDERR 2                            ;error function
%define SYSCALL_EXIT 1                      ;exit 
%define SYSCALL_READ 3                      ;read
%define SYSCALL_WRITE 4                     ;write
%define IDBUFLEN 3                          ;length of id buffer
%define NAMEBUFLEN 500                      ;length of name buffer

;;given data
SECTION .data
    id db "Please enter the id: "           ;prompt for id
    lenid equ $-id                          ;length of id prompt

    name db "Please enter the name: "       ;prompt for name
    lenname equ $-name                      ;length of name

    idlabel db "ID:    "                    ;used for printing end data
    lenidlabel equ $-idlabel                ;length of id label

    namelabel db "NAME: "                   ;used for printing end data
    lennamelabel equ $-namelabel            ;length of name label

    printline db "", 10                     ;new line character


;;unintialized data
SECTION .bss
    id1Buf:        resb IDBUFLEN             ;buffer for id 1
    name1Buf:      resb NAMEBUFLEN           ;buffer for name 1
```

Comment: Tell me what happens when you change resb IDBUFLEN to 4 or 5 instead of 3, then also consider null terminating the string stored in id1Buf.

Comment: @alvonellos when i changed to 4 id1Buf becomes "12\n\000jay\n" if i null terminate it id1Buf becomes "12\000\000jay\n"

Comment: They're running together because of some kind of an offset condition, try using `equ` instead of `%define` for that constant and tell me what happens.

Comment: @alvonellos sorry I'm new to this lang, you put that under the .data section? how would you do that `IDBUFLEN equ 2`

Comment: The syntax is right, but you put it where you have your defines, I believe. Also, when you store the value in that uninitialized data section, move it to some memory variable and work with it from there.

Comment: I'm new to NASM myself, too. When I took assembly in college, I took MASM.

Comment: @alvonellos same thing happens its so weird that they are running together like that because I'm clearly not using id1Buf again in the second read. its a gonna be like a super small problem so hard to find.

Comment: @alvonellos yea I'm taking this for a college course right now

Comment: Your buffers are contiguous, what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankKotler lol sorry I'm pretty dumb, how would you fix that, I thought i created the buffers separately?

Comment: I don't see that it needs fixin'. Tell gdb to display less, perhaps?

Comment: @FrankKotler that is a way, but i have '10 buffers' like that                                                                  `id1Buf: resb IDBUFLEN`
`id2Buf: resb IDBUFLEN`
                   what is the best way to store all those user inputs for easy editing/manipulating later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh, let me make this an "answer" (although I'm not sure it is one). What you're seeing is expected behavior. You've got a three-byte buffer, you've filled it with '1', '2', and '\n'. Immediately following that you've got another (longer) buffer in which you put 'J', 'a', 'y', and '\n'.

Notice that `sys_read` terminates your input with a linefeed (\n), not a zero. It won't return until "enter" is hit. (this applies to STDIN - other files differ) You've got a bigger problem if the pesky user enters "12345(enter)", The first buffer will get '1', '2', '3' - it won't overflow - but after the "name" prompt, it won't pause but '4', '5', '\n' will be put into the name buffer. The solution is to make sure you have the linefeed!

```
; your sys_read
int 80h
push eax ; probably want to save the original length
checkLF:
cmp byte [ecx + eax - 1], LF
jz goodread
mov ecx, dummybuf ; to be thrown away
mov edx, 1
mov ebx, STDIN ; still in there, probably
mov eax, SYSCALL_READ
int 80h
jmp checkLF
goodread:
pop eax  ; get original length back
```

You may wish to zero-terminate the string(s). (maybe should have saved original `ecx` too) `sys_write` doesn't expect a zero-terminated string, but we can find the length and put it in `edx`.

```
mov ecx, buffer ; maybe a parameter?
xor edx, edx
getlen:
cmp byte [ecx + edx], 0
jz gotlen
inc edx
jmp getlen
gotlen:
; rest of your sys_read
```

You ask in a comment how to handle multiple inputs. I'd consider an array of pointers to name strings and an array of pointers to id strings. Possibly an array of lengths (for each?). Take small steps...

```
idarray dd id1buf, id2buf, id3buf, id4buf...
namearray dd name1buf, name2buf, name3buf...
; ...
mov edi, which customer we want
mov esi, [namearray + edi * 4]
; send it off for manipulating
inc edi ; next customer
; find his id?
mov ecx, [idarray + edi * 4]
; send it off to print
```

Something like that, maybe?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that last part with the arrays helped a lot, i got everything working perfectly now.